# How can I truncate a String array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of strings in Swift that I want to shorten to only the first 5. It looks like I cannot do:

```
myArray = myArray[0..<5]
```

because I get a compiler error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type [String] with an index of type Countable Range

So what can I do instead?

Comment: Show your actual code. `myArray[0..<5]` _is_ legal so you don't have what you think you have; this is probably an x-y problem, and we could get to the heart of it if you showed the real code.

Comment: while `myArray[0..<5]` may be legal, `array.prefix(n)` is a safer way since it is bounds safe!

Answer (score 9):

I would say

```
let arr2 = arr1.prefix(5)
```

Keep in mind that the result is a Slice. If you want an array, coerce back to an array. So e.g.

```
var arr1 = // ...
arr1 = Array(arr1.prefix(5))
```

However, the notation `arr1[0..<5]` *is* legal, though with the same proviso: it's a slice and would need to be cast back to an array in order to assign it where an array is expected.

Answer (score 4):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
n = 5
array.prefix(n)
```